# Globally distributed accomplices for improved outcome in race attack

Tags: doublespend, race-attack

Would it help you to win a race attack if you had accomplices from all over the world, say Berlin, Beijing, Boston, and Buenos Aires all propagate your transaction to the nodes that they're connected to, when trying to execute a double spend?

Comment: You're obviously missing Brisbane! ;)